# concatenate several files generated by send to kindle amazon plugin to consolidate multiple page documents

Tags: kindle, amazon, send-to-kindle

I'm happily using the [Amazon Kindle chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-to-kindle-for-google/cgdjpilhipecahhcilnafpblkieebhea) but very often the web pages I would like to read on my kindle are split among different pages, for example in the case of pagination, or separate chapters.

I would like to be able to concatenate the content of several pages together, so that I have a consolidated file with the entire text.

I found online a few tutorials to convert the azw3 files from my kindle to pdf, which I could then concatenate and reupload to the kindle, but that's not what I am after, although it is an option, in case I have no alternatives.

For some password protected pages, I found sendtoreader.com composer, but that doesn't work on the password protected pages.

How to get this concatenation done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [GrabMyBooks](http://grabmybooks.com/).
It can be used to grab webpages and create an ebook from them; I don't own a Kindle and I don't recall if it saves in formats other than ePub, but you can easily use Calibre to convert it if needed. You can send the ebook to your device then and read it like any other ebook.

Another possible solution, if it integrates also with Kindle (it does with my Kobo), is to use [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not what I would call concatenation, at it involves removal directives.

I recommend you try to use the editor that comes with Calibre which should work on your (unprotected) files. For those files that are DRM protected, you should first check if you are allowed to change them in the way you want in the first place.

The process of removing directives for pagination and/or new chapters can probably be automated with some programming, but that is far less trivial compared to trying the first ebook(s) by hand in a WYSIWYG editor.